# Using polymer paper-dialog in angular2 typescript app

Tags: typescript, angular, polymer

I'have import the paper-dialog from bower. but I can't show the dialog using open() method.

**app.component.html**

```
<paper-icon-button icon="social:person-outline" data-dialog="dialog" id="sing_in_dialog" (click)="clickHandler()"></paper-icon-button>
<paper-dialog id="dialog" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
   <h2>Dialog Title</h2>
   <p>cia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</paper-dialog>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { PolymerElement } from '@vaadin/angular2-polymer';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  events: ['event: iron-overlay-opened', 'event: iron-overlay-closed'],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [
ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
PolymerElement('vaadin-combo-box'),
PolymerElement('paper-button'),
PolymerElement('paper-scroll-header-panel'),
PolymerElement('paper-toolbar'),
PolymerElement('paper-drawer-panel'),
PolymerElement('paper-header-panel'),
PolymerElement('paper-toolbar'),
PolymerElement('iron-icon'),
PolymerElement('paper-icon-button'),
PolymerElement('paper-toolbar'),
PolymerElement('paper-dialog')
]
})
export class AppComponent {

 constructor() {
 }
   title = "title";

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 clickHandler(e) {
  var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
  if (dialog) {
    dialog.open();
  }
}
}
```

it's give error

> that open() is not HTMLelement function.

what is the error in my code and how we fire polyemer element's method in typescript and angular2. I'm using angular cli to creat project and vaadin  for use polymer in my application. paper-scrol-header, paper-drawer and many other element can be use without error but when we need to call element's method in typescript getting errors and I cant't resolve this and help would be appriciated..

Comment: import the "paper-dialog" in the JS

Comment: i have import PolymerElement('paper-dialog') in app.component.ts

Comment: then maybe the install (paper-dialog) did not actually inject the component into your project at the path where the import looks for it

Comment: I don't get what you saying?.

Comment: 2 steps .... install the component (paper-dialog) in your project .... #2   import and use the component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just need to change clickHandler function into..

```
clickHandler(e) {
  var dialog :any = document.getElementById('dialog');
  if (dialog) {
     dialog.open();
}
```

using :any cast the html element.